# How to add a blank selection to a PHP dropdown query?

Tags: php, mysql

In the dropdown created, it auto selects the first employee name from the list. And when a different employee is selected, the page refreshes with the first employee on the list selected again. Is there a way to make the default selection a blank?

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM employee";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { unset($name); $name = $row['name'];
echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>'; }
```

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: Hint: Add another `echo` outside the loop.

Comment: @tadman I agree, but I have to admit I do that sometimes specifically for SO posts to make the SQL fit on one line without scrolling. I guess I'm setting a bad example, now that you mention it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm not sure what you mean. You can always space out your code better to avoid wrapping issues. I've just seen too many situations where people think `$sql = "..."` is enough to actually *execute* that SQL.

Answer (score 1):

add default value, like:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { unset($name); $name = $row['name']; 

echo '<option value="'.$name.'"'.($isDefaultValue ? "selected":"").'>'.$name.'</option>'; }
```

you need to create $isDefaultValue variable which determines if given record is default, or if you want to create first blank entry use:

```
echo '<option value="-1" selected>This is only default value, pick real one!</option>';
```

and then check in your controller if user picked 'default' -1 value or real one

Comment: Is something wrong with the syntax here? Seems like it's missing a quotation or something

Comment: @T.C. fixed my typo

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Since the default selection shows on the bottom of the list, is there a way to have it show on the top?

Comment: @T.C. so you want to make some records marked as default and selected in select and make them first? then you need to echo it first and then skip it in while loop or sort records and make default first

Comment: And is there a way to make this default selection not searchable? Because it searches and returns a value of -1 in the table

Comment: @T.C. whole thing is about marking default value to something that doesn't occur in database and knowing when to skip searching and/or display error that user has picked default value